# Userform Textbox to work like an html textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to get a textbox in an excel userform to update like an HTML textbox. For instance, if you have a default value set to "First Name" and you click in that textbox, it will disappear and let you type in. Once you click out, if you didn't type anything, it will go back to the default "First Name".

I have found quite a few asking about this same type of thing, but none are working for me. Here is my code so far.

```
Sub QCToolsForm()
QCTools.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub RUBSTotalExpense_Enter()
Debug.Print "Enter"
If Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = "Total Expense" Then
    Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = ""
End If
End Sub

Private Sub RUBSTotalExpense_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Debug.Print "Exit"
If Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = "" Then
    Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = "Total Expense"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
updateDefault

End Sub

Public Function updateDefault()

If Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = "" Then
    Me.RUBSTotalExpense.Value = "Total Expense"
End If

End Function
```

The exit sub is not running until I close the userform. I have also tried lose and getfocus with no luck with those at all. I have also tried before and afterupdate, but they only work the first time. I want it to disappear every time you click in the box if the value is "Total Expense". How do I get the exit sub or something similar to run when I leave the textbox?

[image: Userform]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using your code for Enter and Exit and it worked for me with a test userform. It's updating the field correctly, and printing "Enter" when you select the textbox and "Exit" when you select something else on the userform. Note that for Exit to trigger you need to give focus to something else on the userform. Simply clicking elsewhere will not take focus from the textbox, you must click on another textbox or other control.

I suggest using Debug.Print to observe exactly when each method you try is being called, so that you can be sure when your code is running.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Debug.Print "Enter"
    If TextBox1.Value = "Total Expense" Then
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "Exit"
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        TextBox1.Value = "Total Expense"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have been able to get the exit function working by changing it to an afterupdate. The problem I get now is that enter only runs the first time I click in the box.

Comment: That is because AfterUpdate (and BeforeUpdate) only trigger if the content of the textbox is actually changed. The contents are automatically being changed the first time when your Enter event changes the value to "". The next time you enter, the value is already "" and it is not modified.

                                       edit: If you type something in the textbox, exit it, then delete that entry and leave again, THEN the AfterUpdate should run a second time because both i) the value changed, and ii) the value is blank.

Comment: Not quite, when I open up the UserForm, it shows "Total Expense". I click it, it updates to a blank to type it in. Once I leave it for something else and leave it blank, it updates to "Total Expense" again. But upon returning, it stays as "Total Expense" instead of going blank.

Comment: I updated to your code and doesn't do either of the things I am trying to accomplish, it doesn't go blank or update to Total Expense when left blank.

Comment: I'm not sure why then. I have a simple userform with two textboxes, a checkbox, and a commandbutton, and the above code works. It changes the blank entry to "Total Expense" when I select any of the other controls in the userform. Can you post your entire useform/code? Can you confirm you're not seeing the debug output from my code in Enter/Exit?

Comment: I can confirm that I am getting enter, but exit only works on closing the userform.

Comment: As for posting everything, I can do that, but are you just looking for a picture of my userform?

Comment: That was what I was thinking, because I cannot replicate your issues with my simple userform. But you said you are getting enter. Do you mean after the first time as well? Both Exit/Enter trigger for me when I switch (repeatedly) between controls on the userform. Do you have another textbox you can switch the cursor to? If you have no other controls to get "focus", then I can see why Exit would only trigger when you close the userform.

Comment: I have update my question to have a picture of my userform and all of my code that is currently active in the userform, as well as the sub to call the form.

Comment: I figured it out! That is really dumb... it is because my textbox is in a frame, it will only recognize the exit if you leave within the frame...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I knew that was the case with the userform as a whole, but I forgot about frames. Frames have an exit/enter event you can use as well..

Comment: I really appreciate your help in working through this, sometimes it just takes a sounding board. Marked as the answer since you were correct, even though userforms are dumb...